# solrj: using a POJO with non-string fields

Tags: solr, pojo, solrj

I'm brand-new to solr and solrj, and investigating them as a potential platform for a search-oriented app.

We have a lot of data in a MongoDB instance, with pojos defined in Java. I'd like to migrate the data over to solr using my existing MongoDB POJOs, by adding solrj `@Field` annotations.

This seems to work fine for String fields, but not so much for ints:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERRORunknown_field_downloadsCount
```

Is there a simple way to get solrj to automatically map ints (and potentially other non-string types) to String?

I guess I could just alter my class with something like:

```
@Field("downloadCount")
String getDownloadCountAsString() { return Integer.toString(downloadCount); }
```

But I was wondering if there was a more robust solution.

Comment: The error suggests that you don't have a 'downloadsCount' field. Do you have it in your schema.xml?

Comment: doh... that was exactly what was happening. Quite by chance, my POJO had several fields with the same name as the default schema in the examples dir ("id", "title", "price"), and when these worked for me out of the box, I had mistakenly assumed that I didn't *need* to create a schema.  Why not turn your comment into an answer so I can give you proper credit?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error suggests that you don't have a 'downloadsCount' field in the Solr schema. Check your schema.xml.